# How to sort the columns in the below code

Tags: reactjs

How to filter the columns? Here I need a date filter column, When we click the header of the date, it automatically sorts the column.
Actually, they asked like this "Need to sort by date and stick the 6 newest on this one as well"
Can you please help with this?
Here is the code I used.

Comment: give us a row example. how does a row look like in json format? what type is e.g. voucherdate?

Comment: Just added image

Comment: so `voucherdate` is of `Date` type? or a string?

Comment: added json format

Comment: Added json data image. Please check and help me

Comment: can you please add a json snippet of this list too in order to work with this? thnx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234401/discussion-between-venusri-and-apostolos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a helper function in order to parse the string to `Date` object.
Then you can apply the sorting

Check the code snippet.
I store the `Date` object into another property in order not to break anything. You can of course replace it with the current property and format it accordingly inside your table cell.

```js
function parseStr(str) {
  let parts =str.substring(0, 10).split('.');
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]); 
}

let array = [
{
"number":"5421787",
"amount":1391.74,
"duedate":"28.08.2020 00.00.00",
"voucherdate":"14.08.2020 00.00.00",
"invoicelink":"",
"status":"Betalt"
},
{
"number":"5499047",
"amount":499.0,
"duedate":"29.09.2020 00.00.00",
"voucherdate":"15.09.2020 00.00.00",
"invoicelink":"",
"status":"Betalt"
},
{
"number":"5574780",
"amount":499.0,
"duedate":"29.10.2020 00.00.00",
"voucherdate":"15.10.2020 00.00.00",
"invoicelink":"",
"status":"Betalt"
}

]

console.log(array.map(obj => ({ ...obj, voucherdate2: parseStr(obj.voucherdate)})).sort((a,b) => b.voucherdate2.getTime() - a.voucherdate2.getTime()))
```

So in your code

```
  const invoiceData = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer.invoices)
  let sortableInvoiceData = invoiceData.map(obj => ({ ...obj, voucherdate2: parseStr(obj.voucherdate)})).sort((a,b) => b.voucherdate2.getTime() - a.voucherdate2.getTime())
  const renderInvoices = sortableInvoiceData.map((invoice, index) => {
```